# Validate in Regex 5 Different Numbers (Do Not Validate Repeated Numbers)

Tags: php, regex

Need help!

I've Searched A Lot Here On The Site And I Can't Find How To Make My REGEX

```
([0-9])(?!\d*\0)){5}
```

**5 Digits** Validate Unrepeated Number Sequences!

```
00000 (False)
11111 (False)
22222 (False)
33333 (False)
```

I would like you to validate it just like this below.

```
00001 (Match)
11110 (Match)
22220 (Match)
12345 (Match)
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Did you try `'/(?!(\d)\1{4})\d{5}/'`? Or `'/(?<!\d)(?!(\d)\1{4})\d{5}(?!\d)/'`

Comment: `00001` is not 5 different numbers.

Comment: Isn't there something missing?
or is 'a12345' valid?

Comment: Please let know if my solution works or not to see what exact requirements you've got. It will help us to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand the question it doesn't require a regular expression in PHP.

```php
<?php
$arr = ['', '00000','11111','22222','33333','00001','11110','22220','12345', '12234'];

echo '<pre> ltrim + ltrim : ';
foreach($arr as $el) // not 5 times the same digit using ltrim
    if (strlen($el) == 5 && ltrim($el, '0..9') === '' && ltrim($el, $el[0]) !== '')
         echo "$el, ";

echo "\n ctype + ltrim ";
foreach($arr as $el) // not 5 times the same digit using ctype
    if (ctype_digit($el) && strlen($el) == 5 && ltrim($el, $el[0]) !== '')
         echo "$el, ";

echo "\n count_chars : ";
foreach($arr as $el) // 5 different digits using count_chars
    if (ctype_digit($el) && count(count_chars($el, 1)) == 5) 
       echo "$el, ";

echo "\n array_flip : ";
foreach($arr as $el) // 5 differents digits using array_flip
    if (strlen($el) == 5 && ctype_digit($el) && count(array_flip(str_split($el))) == 5) 
  echo("$el, ");

$N = 2;

echo "\n preg_match with N=$N : ";
foreach($arr as $el) // not N digit repeated with preg_match
    if (preg_match('#^(?!.*([0-9])\1{' . ($N - 1) . '}.*)[0-9]{5}$#', $el)) 
  echo("$el, ");

/*
 ltrim + ltrim : 00001, 11110, 22220, 12345, 12234, 
 ctype + ltrim 00001, 11110, 22220, 12345, 12234, 
 count_chars : 12345, 
 array_flip : 12345, 
 preg_match with N=2 : 12345, 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Solving the problem with simple string functions becomes simple and easy to understand.

```
$valid = ctype_digit($str) && strlen($str) === 5 && str_replace($str[0],'',$str) !== '';
```

The string is valid if all 5 characters are digits and not all are equal.
str_replace returns an empty string if all characters in the string are the same.

A test:

```
$testData = ['','a123','00000','11111','22222','33333','00001','11110','22220','12345', '12234'];
foreach($testData as $str){
  $valid = ctype_digit($str) && strlen($str) === 5 && str_replace($str[0],'',$str) !== '';
  echo "'".$str."' : ".($valid ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid')."<br>\n";
}
```

output:

```
'' : Invalid
'a123' : Invalid
'00000' : Invalid
'11111' : Invalid
'22222' : Invalid
'33333' : Invalid
'00001' : Valid
'11110' : Valid
'22220' : Valid
'12345' : Valid
'12234' : Valid
```

Of course, this can also be solved with regular expressions.

```
~(?:^([0-9])\1{4}$)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(^[0-9]{5}$)~
```

Understanding this is a case for regEx professionals. Code you don't understand should never be used!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(?<!\d)(?!(\d)\1{4})\d{5}(?!\d)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/YmdUxc/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
Negative Lookbehind (?<!\d):
 - Assert that the Regex below does not match
   - \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
Negative Lookahead (?!(\d)\1{4})
 - Assert that the Regex below does not match
   - 1st Capturing Group (\d)
   - \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
   - \1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
   - {4} matches the previous token exactly 4 times
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
{5} matches the previous token exactly 5 times
Negative Lookahead (?!\d)
 - Assert that the Regex below does not match
  - \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
```